# SNI not working ubuntu 14.04, multiple virtual host SSL on same IP

Tags: apache2, openssl

Ubuntu 14.04 with standard LAMP install.

on single IP, I am trying to run two websites using SSL with SNI. I have two diff certs and they are being applied correctly. My issue is redirection from HTTP to correct HTTPS website.

I am testing with latest firefox and TLS is correctly setup.

so, in short every HTTP request is getting redirected to ....

I checked with rewrite module by disabling/enabling, found no differences

sites enabled:

(main site) `dev.domain.com.conf`. Its contents are regular SSL virtual host contents...

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName dev.domain.com
        ServerAlias dev.domain.com
...
```

(for redirect to main site over HTTPS, I created this additional virtual host)
`dev.domain.com.80.conf`. Its contents are:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dev.domain.com
        ServerAlias dev.domain.com
        ServerAdmin xxxxxxx
        Redirect permanent / https://dev.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

(second main site) `www.domain.com.conf`. Its contents are regular SSL vhost...

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
...
```

(for redirect to main site over HTTPS, I created this additional virtual host) `www.domain.com.80.conf`. Its contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        ServerAdmin rxxxxx
        Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Even after adding following to BOTH the virtualhost configs meant for redirection - it didn't help.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

while HTTP `dev.domain.com` correctly transfers to HTTPS `dev.domain.com`, HTTP `www.domain.com` transfers to HTTPS `dev.domain.com`.

Also, if i access https URL for both sites it works correctly. only http to https redirection is not working.

Comment: while HTTP dev.domain.com correctly transfers to HTTPS dev.domain.com,
HTTP www.domain.com transfers to HTTPS dev.domain.com

Comment: Also, if i access https URL for both sites it works correctly. only http to https redirection is not working.

Comment: OP reverted everything tried. Says it was probably a browser cache issue [Should I blame caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Answer (score 0):

maybe it was browser cache, after countless editing all over various apache config. here is the summary:

1. mod_rewrite: not required.
2. NameVirtualHost: not required.
3. one virtual host configured for redirection purposes, for each site.
4. above redirection commands in them.

thats it.

Comment: Please add details to the step 3 of the answer. Which configuration at last worked. Otherwise I think the answer isn't helpful at all.